# Custom megameu walker need improvement

Tags: walker, sub-menu

I'am working on a custom megamenu that will look like

```
        <li class="l-nav-item l-mega dropdown"><button class="open-icon visible-xs fa fa-angle-down"></button><a href=" ">Services</a>
            <div class="l-nav-mega dropdown-menu full-width">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                  <a class="mega-title" href="">Tite from submenu 1</a>
                  <hr>
                  <a href=""><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>Link from submenu level 2</a>
                  <a href=""><i class="fa fa-laptop"></i>Portfolio</a>
                  <a href=""><i class="fa fa-tablet"></i>Responsive</a>
                  <a href=""><i class="fa fa-cc-visa"></i>Layouts</a>
                  <a href=""><i class="fa fa-gamepad"></i>Megamenu</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                  <a href="">Title from level 1</a>
                  <hr>
                  <a class="mega-title" href="">Tite from submenu 1</a>
                  <hr>
                  <a href=""><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>Link from submenu level 2</a>
                  <a href=""><i class="fa fa-recycle"></i>Responsive</a>
                  <a href=""><i class="fa fa-paw"></i>Layouts</a>
                  <a href=""><i class="fa fa-magic"></i>Megamenu</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                  <a class="mega-title" href="">Tite from submenu 1</a>
                  <hr>
                  <a href=""><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>Link from submenu level 2</a>
                  <a href=""><i class="fa fa-rocket"></i>Responsive</a>
                  <a href=""><i class="fa fa-cab"></i>Layouts</a>
                  <a href=""><i class="fa fa-microphone"></i>Megamenu</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                  <a class="mega-title" href="">Tite from submenu 1</a>
                  <hr>
                  <a href=""><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>Link from submenu level 2</a>
                  <a href=""><i class="fa fa-google"></i>Responsive</a>
                  <a href=""><i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i>Layouts</a>
                  <a href=""><i class="fa fa-android"></i>Megamenu</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                  <a class="mega-title" href="">Tite from submenu 1</a>
                  <hr>
                  <a href=""><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>Link from submenu level 2</a>
                  <a href=""><i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i>Responsive</a>
                  <a href=""><i class="fa fa-google-wallet"></i>Layouts</a>
                  <a href=""><i class="fa fa-bitcoin"></i>Megamenu</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                  <a class="mega-title" href="">Tite from submenu 1</a>
                  <hr>
                  <a href=""><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>Link from submenu level 2</a>
                  <a href=""><i class="fa fa-euro"></i>Responsive</a>
                  <a href=""><i class="fa fa-rouble"></i>Layouts</a>
                  <a href=""><i class="fa fa-jpy"></i>Megamenu</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
```

I'm using those variables

```
private $megamenu_state;
private $column_state;
private $megatype_state;
private $megamenu_start;
private $column_total = 0;
```

to get data from menu input

[image]

I want the megamenu to be from the 2nd submenu and not from the first like the picture below

[image: Mega menu structure wanted]

and not like my current megamenu

[image: Current mega menu]

this is my walker

```
class Mega_Eddy_Walker_Nav_Menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

private $megamenu_state;
private $column_state;
private $megatype_state;
private $megamenu_start;
private $column_total = 0;
// Add .dropdown and a caret to dropdown links
function display_element($element, &$children_elements, $max_depth = 0, $depth=0, $args, &$output) {
    $id_field = $this->db_fields['id'];
    $megamenu = 0;
       $column = 1;
       if($depth == 1){
            $column = get_post_meta( $item->menu_item_parent, '_menu_item_column', true );
            $megamenu = get_post_meta( $item->menu_item_parent, '_menu_item_megamenu', true );
            $mega_type = get_post_meta( $item->menu_item_parent, '_menu-item-megatype', true );
       }
    // if(!empty($children_elements[$element->$id_field]) && $megamenu == 0 ) {
    //     $element->title .= '<button class="fa fa-plus visible-xs visible-ms"></button> <b class="caret"></b>';
    // }

if ( is_object( $args[0] ) ) {
    $args[0]->has_children = ! empty( $children_elements[$element->$id_field] );
}
    Walker_Nav_Menu::display_element($element, $children_elements, $max_depth, $depth, $args, $output);

}

function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0)
  {
       global $wp_query;

       $megamenu = 0;
       $column = 1;
       if($depth == 1){
            $column = get_post_meta( $item->menu_item_parent, '_menu_item_column', true );
            $megamenu = get_post_meta( $item->menu_item_parent, '_menu_item_megamenu', true );
            $megatype = get_post_meta( $item->menu_item_parent, '_menu-item-megatype', true );
       }


        $this->megamenu_state = $item->megamenu;
        $this->column_state = $item->column;
        $this->megatype_state = $item->megatype;



        $mejamenu = wp_get_nav_menu_object($item->menu_item_parent);
    var_dump($mejamenu);


       $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

       $class_names = $value = '';

       $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
       $labelclass = (isset($item->nav_label) && ($item->nav_label == 1))? ' show-label' : ' hide-label';
       $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item ) );
       $class_names = '';
       $submenu = ($depth == 0 || !$args->has_children)? '':' dropdown ';
       $button = ($args->has_children)?'<button class="open-icon visible-xs fa fa-angle-down"></button>':'';




       if($this->megamenu_start == 1 && $depth == 1){
        $class_names = '';
       }
       else{
       $class_names = esc_attr( $class_names ). $labelclass;
        }
       $classo = ($depth == 0 && $item->megamenu == 1 )? '<li class="l-nav-item l-mega dropdown menu-item-':'<li class="l-nav-item dropdown menu-item-';
       $classo = ($depth == 1 && $this->megamenu_start == 1) ? '': $classo;
       $classo = ($depth != 0 && $this->megamenu_start == 0 ) ? '<li class="l-nav-subitem dropdown menu-item-': $classo;
       if(!isset($item->column) || $item->column == 0){
        $item->column = 1;
       }
       if($this->megamenu_start == 1){
       $columns = 12/$item->column;
       $column_total += $columns;

        }

        $column_break == ($column_total % 12 == 0) ? '<div class="clearfix">' : '';

       if($this->megamenu_start == 1 && $depth == 1 && $this->megatype_start != 4){
        $output .= $indent.'<div class="col-md-'.$columns.' col-sm-4">';
       }
       elseif($this->megamenu_start == 1 && $depth == 1 && $this->megatype_start == 4){
        $output .= $indent;
       }
       else{
        $output .= $indent . $classo . $item->ID . $value . $class_names.'">'.$button;
       }



       $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
       $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
       $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
       $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';



       $description  = ! empty( $item->description ) ? '<span class="'.esc_attr( $item->description ).'"></span>' : '';

      /** if($depth != 0){
           $description = $append = $prepend = "";
       }*/

        $item_tag = ($this->megamenu_start == 0 || $depth != 1) ? '<a' : '';
        $item_tag_close = ($this->megamenu_start == 0 || $depth != 1) ? '</a>' : '';
        $item_tag = ($this->megamenu_start == 0 || $depth != 1) ? '<a' : '';
        $item_tag_close = ($this->megamenu_start == 0 || $depth != 1) ? '</a>' : '';
        $item_tag = ($this->megamenu_start == 0 || $depth != 1) ? '<a' : '';
        $item_tag_close = ($this->megamenu_start == 0 || $depth != 1) ? '</a>' : '';

        if($this->megamenu_start == 0 || $depth != 1){
        $item_output = $args->before;
        $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'><i class="'.$item->subtitle.'"></i>';
        $item_output .= $args->link_before .$prepend.apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ).$append;
        $item_output .= $args->link_after;
        $item_output .= $description.'</a>';
        $item_output .= $args->after;
        }

        if($this->megamenu_start == 1 && $depth == 1 && $item->megatype == 1){
        $columns = ($this->column_state);
        $columns = ($this->column_state == 0) ? 2 : $columns;
        $item_output = $args->before;
        $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'><i class="'.$item->subtitle.'"></i>';
        $item_output .= $args->link_before .$prepend.apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ).$append;
        $item_output .= $args->link_after;
        $item_output .= $description.$megawidget.'</a>';
        $item_output .= $args->after;
        }

        if($this->megamenu_start == 1 && $depth == 1 && $item->megatype == 2){
        $columns = ($this->column_state);
        $columns = ($this->column_state == 0) ? 3 : $columns;
        $item_output = $args->before;
        $item_output .= '<a class="image-thumbnail ratio-4-3"'. $attributes .'>';
        $item_output .= '<img src="'.$item->subtitle.'" alt="...">';
        $item_output .= '</a>';
        }


        if($this->megamenu_start == 1 && $depth == 1 && $item->megatype == 4){
        $columns = ($this->column_state);
        $columns = ($this->column_state == 0) ? 2 : $columns;
        ob_start();
        the_widget( 'Aderna_Megamenu_Widget' );
        $widget = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        $item_output .= $widget;

        }

        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
        }

public function end_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {

    $classo = ($depth == 1 && $this->megamenu_start == 1) ? '</div>': '</li>';
    if($this->megamenu_start == 1 && $this->megatype_start == 4 && $depth == 1){
        $classo = '';
    }

    $output .= $classo."\n";
}
// Add .dropdown-menu to the submenu
function start_lvl( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array()) {

    global $wp_query;

       $megamenu = 0;
       $column = 1;
        if($depth == 1){
        $column = get_post_meta( $item->menu_item_parent, '_menu_item_column', true );
        $megamenu = get_post_meta( $item->menu_item_parent, '_menu_item_megamenu', true );
        $megamenu_type = get_post_meta( $item->menu_item_parent, '_menu_item_megatype', true );
        }

    if ($this->megamenu_state == 0){
        $classes = array( 'l-nav-sublist dropdown-menu' );
    }
    if ($this->megamenu_state == 1)
    {

        $classes = array( 'l-nav-mega dropdown-menu full-width' );
        }
    $class_names = implode( ' ', $classes );
    // build html
   // $instyle = ($this->megamenu_state == 1)?'<ul class="':'<ul class="';

        if ( $this->megamenu_state == 1 ) {
            $instyle = '<div class="';
            $rowstyle ='<div class="row">';
        } else {
            $instyle = '<ul class="';
            $rowstyle = '';
        }


   $output .= "\n" . $indent . $instyle . $class_names . '">'."\n".$rowstyle."\n";

$this->megamenu_start = $this->megamenu_state;
   $this->megatype_start = $this->megatype_state;

}


function end_lvl(&$output, $depth=0, $args=array()) {

        if ( $this->megamenu_start == 1 ) {
            $instyle = '</div>'.$indent."\n".'</div>';
        }
        else {
            $instyle = '</ul>';
        }

    // $instyle = ($this->megamenu_state == 1)?'</div>':'</ul>';
    $output .= $indent.$instyle."\n";


}
}
```

html code output by the walker

```
<li class="l-nav-item l-mega dropdown menu-item-750 show-label"><button class="open-icon visible-xs fa fa-angle-down"></button><a href="http://localhost/wordpress-kaiogen/category/home-slider/"><i class="fa fa-wifi"></i>Home Slider</a>
  <div class="l-nav-mega dropdown-menu full-width">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress-kaiogen/activity/"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>Activity</a></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4"><a class="image-thumbnail ratio-4-3" href="http://localhost/wordpress-kaiogen/sample-page/"><img src="http://www.whatsappfor.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/tablets-montage.jpg" alt="..."></a></div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress-kaiogen/about-us-2/"><i class="fa fa-paw"></i>About us</a></div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress-kaiogen/services/"><i class="fa fa-magic"></i>services</a></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4"><a class="image-thumbnail ratio-4-3" href="http://localhost/wordpress-kaiogen/about-us/"><img src="http://cdn.liliputing.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/surface-21.jpg" alt="..."></a>   </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress-kaiogen/members/"><i class="fa fa-laptop"></i>Members</a></div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress-kaiogen/groups/"><i class="fa fa-cc-visa"></i>Groups</a></div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress-kaiogen/shop/"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>Shop</a></div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress-kaiogen/columns/"><i class="fa fa-google"></i>Columns</a></div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress-kaiogen/checkout/"><i class="fa fa-microphone"></i>Checkout</a></div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress-kaiogen/my-account/"><i class="https://cdn3.pcadvisor.co.uk/cmsdata/features/3451310/Tablet_Group_test_206PCA_206_Photoshoot-212.jpg"></i>My Account</a></div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress-kaiogen/cart/"><i class="fa fa-wordpress"></i>Cart</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

Note : with my current walker if i added a second level submenu all thing break and becomes like

```
<li class="l-nav-item l-mega dropdown menu-item-750 show-label"><button class="open-icon visible-xs fa fa-angle-down"></button><a href="http://localhost/wordpress-kaiogen/category/home-slider/"><i class="fa fa-wifi"></i>Home Slider</a>
 <div class="l-nav-mega dropdown-menu full-width">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress-kaiogen/activity/"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>Activity</a></div>
   <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4"><a class="image-thumbnail ratio-4-3" href="http://localhost/wordpress-kaiogen/sample-page/"><img src="http://www.whatsappfor.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/tablets-montage.jpg" alt="..."></a>
     <ul class="l-nav-sublist dropdown-menu">

       <li class="l-nav-subitem dropdown menu-item-116 show-label"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress-kaiogen/about-us-2/"><i class="fa fa-paw"></i>About us</a>      </li>
     </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="l-nav-subitem dropdown menu-item-755 show-label"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress-kaiogen/services/"><i class="fa fa-magic"></i>services</a></li>
  <li class="l-nav-subitem dropdown menu-item-754 show-label"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress-kaiogen/about-us/"><i class="http://cdn.liliputing.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/surface-21.jpg"></i>Portfolio</a></li>
  <li class="l-nav-subitem dropdown menu-item-1416 show-label"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress-kaiogen/members/"><i class="fa fa-laptop"></i>Members</a></li>
  <li class="l-nav-subitem dropdown menu-item-1415 show-label"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress-kaiogen/groups/"><i class="fa fa-cc-visa"></i>Groups</a></li>
  <li class="l-nav-subitem dropdown menu-item-1421 show-label"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress-kaiogen/shop/"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>Shop</a></li>
  <li class="l-nav-subitem dropdown menu-item-758 show-label"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress-kaiogen/columns/"><i class="fa fa-google"></i>Columns</a></li>
  <li class="l-nav-subitem dropdown menu-item-1419 show-label"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress-kaiogen/checkout/"><i class="fa fa-microphone"></i>Checkout</a></li>
  <li class="l-nav-subitem dropdown menu-item-1418 show-label"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress-kaiogen/my-account/"><i class="https://cdn3.pcadvisor.co.uk/cmsdata/features/3451310/Tablet_Group_test_206PCA_206_Photoshoot-212.jpg"></i>My Account</a></li>
  <li class="l-nav-subitem dropdown menu-item-1420 show-label"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress-kaiogen/cart/"><i class="fa fa-wordpress"></i>Cart</a>  </li>
 </ul>
</li>
```

Finally i think the walker code look crapy so i hope you help me to clean or use better alternative coding techniques